# SQL INSERT Using WHILE LOOP and SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, while-loop

Need to add a bunch of repetitive records to the database and don't want to do all of it by hand.

Need to add the intial records by hand but then want to create a query I can run to essentially template rest of the records and then just change the one different field by hand.

Problem is, I don't know exactly what the initial records are until I enter them.

For example

```
 FieldOne | FieldTwo   | FieldThree
----------+------------+--------------
 Text One | Text Two A | int Three A
 Text One | Text Two B | int Three A
 Text One | Text Two C | int Three A
 ...
```

This all has to be done by hand. I then need to create:

```
 FieldOne | FieldTwo   | FieldThree
----------+------------+--------------
 Text One | Text Two A | int Three B
 Text One | Text Two B | int Three B
 Text One | Text Two C | int Three B
 ...
```

... repeat for all the different values in Field Two.

Hope that makes sense?

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
WHILE (SELECT ALL DISTINCT VALUES FIELDTWO)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Same all the time', Value From the FieldTwo Select, 'Same all the time')
END
```

Can this be done in SQL Server and can you give me the exact T-SQL statement to do it?

Comment: Use the code button(like i've done with the sql) instead of `</br>` tags since it's impossible now to reformat your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (fieldtwo, fieldone, fieldthree)
SELECT DISTINCT fieldtwo, 'Same all the time',  'Same all the time' From TABLE2
```

Comment: Awesome. Simple but effective! Thanks.

Comment: This answer has been so handy for a project I have been working on. Thank you so much for a nice specifc use-case insert query!